# ORDER BY without Total in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, rollup

I have this SQL query, which uses `ROLLUP` to get the total but also needs to order every other row by the amount:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL([SharepointId], 'Total') as 'Sharepoint', 
    Count([Id]) as 'Nombre de tickets' 
FROM [dbo].[Tickets]
GROUP BY ROLLUP([SharepointId])
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1
```

Is there a way to make sure the total stays at the end of the results while keeping the descending order of the other rows?

For now, this is what I get:

```
Sharepoint         Nombre de tickets
------------------ -----------------
Total              20326
INTERNE            9396
MAIN               1503
...
```

Comment: If you change the order by clause to ascending, then you will definitely ensure that the total is always last, unless all ticket counts are zero: `ORDER BY 2 ASC, 1`

Comment: @PeterAbolins If only it could be that simple, I need to keep the descending order.

Comment: `ORDER BY GROUPING([SharepointId]), COUNT([id]) DESC` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are mis-representing what you want.

- You don't want a row to be last because it's NULL
- You want a row to be last because it's been grouped

SQL Server has a function for exactly that, and the docs page has almost exactly your example in it...

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL([SharepointId], 'Total') as 'Sharepoint', 
    Count([Id]) as 'Nombre de tickets' 
FROM [dbo].[Tickets]
GROUP BY ROLLUP([SharepointId])
ORDER BY GROUPING([SharepointId]), 2 DESC
```

`GROUPING([SharepointId])` is `0` when the column is **not** grouped *(so those rows sort first)* and then it's `1` when the column **is** grouped *(so that row goes last)*.  This is especially useful when rolling up multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL([SharepointId], 'Total') as [Sharepoint], 
    Count([Id]) as [Nombre de tickets]
FROM [dbo].[Tickets]
GROUP BY ROLLUP([SharepointId])
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [SharepointId] IS NULL THEN 'B' ELSE 'A' END, [Nombre de tickets] DESC
```

Comment: I can't really just add another meaningless column as the result needs to be human-readable.

Comment: That will not run, I don't think `ISNULL` can be used that way.

Comment: it was just a miss-typing. Added a space to make it IS NULL

Comment: Thanks! ended up merging both answers with `ORDER BY CASE WHEN [SharepointId] IS NOT NULL THEN Count([Id]) END DESC, 1`

Comment: glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Order By clause as below :

```
CASE WHEN  ISNULL([SharepointId], 'Total') <>'Total' THEN  
Count([Id])END DESC, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `case` expression :

```
order by (case when SharepointId is null then 1 else 0 end), [Nombre de tickets] desc;
```